# Using PTP on DSA-Style Switch Makes Packets Look Distorted

Tags: linux, network-interface, ip, bridge

So I have an Altera Cyclone V SoC board running Linux 5.7.10 containing a BCM53125 rev4 switch, three LAN ports, and one CPU port (the NIC). Distributed Switch Architecture is in use, so my setup looks as follows:

```
                 ------- lan1
                 |
eth0 (CPU) --- Switch -- lan2
                 |
                 ------- lan3
```

I want to get PTP with hardware timestamping running on this machine. Now, ethtool shows only for eth0 correct capabilities (tested using `ethtool -T eth0`), that is,

```
# ethtool -T eth0
Time stamping parameters for eth0:
Capabilities:
        hardware-transmit     (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_HARDWARE)
        software-transmit     (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_SOFTWARE)
        hardware-receive      (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_HARDWARE)
        software-receive      (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_SOFTWARE)
        software-system-clock (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_SOFTWARE)
        hardware-raw-clock    (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RAW_HARDWARE)
PTP Hardware Clock: 0
Hardware Transmit Timestamp Modes:
        off                   (HWTSTAMP_TX_OFF)
        on                    (HWTSTAMP_TX_ON)
Hardware Receive Filter Modes:
        none                  (HWTSTAMP_FILTER_NONE)
        all                   (HWTSTAMP_FILTER_ALL)
        ptpv1-l4-event        (HWTSTAMP_FILTER_PTP_V1_L4_EVENT)
        ptpv1-l4-sync         (HWTSTAMP_FILTER_PTP_V1_L4_SYNC)
        ptpv1-l4-delay-req    (HWTSTAMP_FILTER_PTP_V1_L4_DELAY_REQ)
        ptpv2-l4-event        (HWTSTAMP_FILTER_PTP_V2_L4_EVENT)
        ptpv2-l4-sync         (HWTSTAMP_FILTER_PTP_V2_L4_SYNC)
        ptpv2-l4-delay-req    (HWTSTAMP_FILTER_PTP_V2_L4_DELAY_REQ)
        ptpv2-event           (HWTSTAMP_FILTER_PTP_V2_EVENT)
        ptpv2-sync            (HWTSTAMP_FILTER_PTP_V2_SYNC)
        ptpv2-delay-req       (HWTSTAMP_FILTER_PTP_V2_DELAY_REQ)
```

It fails for lan1 and friends:

```
# ethtool -T lan1
Time stamping parameters for lan1:
Cannot get device time stamping settings: Operation not supported
```

So, my question is, how can I use eth0 and its capabilities for communication?

I tried setting up a bridge and, alternatively, IP addresses for each LAN port as described [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/dsa/configuration.html). Then I start a PTP master on the board using eth0 as its network interface:

```
# ./ptp4l -qmi eth0
ptp4l[3658.796]: selected /dev/ptp0 as PTP clock
ptp4l[3658.807]: port 1: INITIALIZING to LISTENING on INIT_COMPLETE
ptp4l[3658.807]: port 0: INITIALIZING to LISTENING on INIT_COMPLETE
ptp4l[3666.525]: port 1: LISTENING to MASTER on ANNOUNCE_RECEIPT_TIMEOUT_EXPIRES
ptp4l[3666.525]: selected local clock 664975.fffe.e52d47 as best master
ptp4l[3666.525]: port 1: assuming the grand master role
```

No problems reported. However, if I capture some packets using Wireshark, those packets look nothing like PTP:

[image: Weird output showing weird packets]

Not only that, they also lack an EtherType (such as 0x8000 for IP) in the Ethernet header, but have
values like 0x0048 or 0x005c instead, which, when interpreted as payload length in accordance with IEEE 802.3, don't even match the real payload length. Here's a detailed description of the first packet in the above image:

[image: Details of first packet elaborating the above]

Here's also a hex dump, for the full range of details:

```
01 00 5e 00 01 81 66 49 75 e5 2d 47 00 5c 02 48
40 00 01 11 8a 4d 0a 00 01 7b e0 00 01 81 01 40
01 40 00 48 06 d3 0b 02 00 40 00 00 00 08 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 49 75 ff fe e5
2d 47 00 01 00 00 05 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 25 00 80 f8 fe ff ff 80 66 49 75 ff fe
e5 2d 47 00 00 a0
```

So right at the link layer stuff already goes awry for some reason. My guess is it has to do with me attaching the PTP master to the CPU port, which the DSA subsystem somehow can't handle/doesn't expect.

So, I'd like to know

1. if this is the way to go to attach directly to eth0, not a LAN port and
2. why the packets are so severely messed up.

I want, in a way, to circumvent DSA. I just happen to be stuck with it, but one port with timestamping capabilities would suffice entirely for my purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those Broadcom chipsets are often either not true switches and often all the ethernet ports are often not full ports per se.

The BCM53125 seems better than the usual ones in cheaper boards in that respect, but even so, you might both not be dealing with the full capabilities of a commercial switch and full ethernet ports.

PTP support seems also nowhere to be seen in the switch [datasheets](https://pt.mouser.com/Datasheets/_/?Keyword=BCM53125&FS=True&utm_source=eciaauthorized&utm_medium=aggregator&utm_campaign=viewall&utm_term=BCM53125), odd ethtool showing it (might have slipped me)

My suspicion is that you might be expecting too much from such humble chipsets.

Comment: I'm aware that the BCM53xx switches don't support PTP, also looked it up in the kernel, no mention of PTP whatsoever. PTP is provided through the MAC controller in the SoC, an STMicroelectronics DWMAC. My problem is how to expose that functionality in eth0 to the outside, including its own IP address. As I added to my question, I just happen to be on a switch, I don't need nor want it per se. And beyond that, it does work somehow, I can observe packets on the wire, but the format is totally off for some weird reason.

Comment: @cadaniluk Broadcom is known for cutting corners on those cheap chipsets...